# Flexible/Fuzzy rule application in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

Assume I have the following predicate `P` and rule `R`:

```
locale example =
  fixes P :: "int ⇒ int ⇒ bool"
  assumes R: "⋀a b c. a ≥ 2 ⟹ P (a*b) (a*c)"
```

I now want to apply the rule to `R` to prove `P 8 4`, but of course a direct rule application fails:

```
lemma (in example) "P 8 4"
proof (rule R)  (* FAILS *)
```

Instead I have to instantiate the equalities manually before using the rule:

```
lemma (in example) "P 8 4"
proof -
  have "P (4*2) (4*1)"
    by (rule R, simp)
  thus "P 8 4" 
    by simp
qed

lemma (in example) "P 8 4"
  using R[where a=2 and b=4 and c=2] by simp
```

The following example is a bit nicer. It only requires a specialized lemma for predicates with 2 arguments and it requires manually specifying the toplevel predicate name:

```
lemma back_subst2: "⟦P x' y'; x' = x; y' = y⟧ ⟹ P x y" 
  by force

lemma (in example) "P 8 4"
proof (rule back_subst2[where P=P], rule R)
  show "2 ≤ (2 :: int)" by simp
  show "2*4 = (8::int)" by simp
  show "2*2 = (4::int)" by simp
qed
```

My question: Is there a better way to apply rules, when arguments do not have the exactly required form? Can the last example be improved somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now written my own method named `fuzzy_rule` to do this:

```
lemma (in example) "P 8 4"
proof (fuzzy_rule R)
  show "2 ≤ (2 :: int)" by simp
  show "2*4 = (8::int)" by simp
  show "2*2 = (4::int)" by simp
qed
```

Source is available at https://github.com/peterzeller/isabelle_fuzzy_rule